# Does NumPy have an inverse of unravel_index()?

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.unravel_index() takes a shape and a flat index into an array, and returns the tuple that represents that index in the array. Is there an inverse? I can compute it by hand, but this seems like it must be a built-in function somewhere...

Comment: I think you should update the accepted answer to the one using `ravel_multi_index`; most people will be using `NumPy 1.6` or newer by now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `numpy 1.6.0` (May 2011) there is a built-in NumPy function [`ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html)

> Converts a tuple of index arrays into an array of flat indices, applying boundary modes to the multi-index.

(This is also mentioned in a comment by user Bi Rico but should really appear as an answer)

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
def ravel_index(pos, shape):
    res = 0
    acc = 1
    for pi, si in zip(reversed(pos), reversed(shape)):
        res += pi * acc
        acc *= si
    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in numpy.ndarray.strides. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html

Comment: Not reliably. When you take slices of arrays, numpy will often share the same data and do stride tricks. Compare arange(15).reshape((3,5)).strides (this will be a nice, contiguous array) and arange(35).reshape((7,5))[1::2,:].strides.

Comment: True, and the non-visibility into that can be a real pain. But if you're planing on doing stride tricks yourself (as I was here), hopefully you can guarantee that the array is contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a built in command, but I've always used the following snippet, assuming numpy's default row-major indexing is being used:

```
np.sum(np.array(index_tuple[:-1])*np.array(a_matrix.shape[1:]))+np.array(index_tuple[-1])
```

for Fortan-like (column-major) indexing, the indices just need to be swapped:

```
np.sum(np.array(index_tuple[1:])*np.array(a_matrix.shape[:-1]))+np.array(index_tuple[0])
```

In the above, index_tuple and a_matrix are a tuple containing the indices of interest and the matrix being indexed, respectively. This does not have the above issue associated with strides when slices are taken.

Comment: As of numpy 1.6 it is a built in command `numpy.ravel_multi_index`, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html
but this question is pretty old.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed the new command, so this is very useful to me.